# Need help in creating parameterized query using Pentaho CDE

Tags: dashboard, pentaho

I am developing one dashboard using Pentaho CDE. I have created one query to fetch organization names from database.
Following query works perfectly for me :

```
select top 5 
employer_name,count(emp_id) as emp_count
from employment_details 
where employer_name=${employer}
group by employer_name 
order by emp_count desc
```

I want to change the where clause so that instead of using `=`, I want to use `like` clause. So I modified query as follows :

```
select top 5 
employer_name,count(emp_id) as emp_count
from employment_details 
where employer_name like ${employer}
group by employer_name 
order by emp_count desc
```

but its not giving me proper results. For example, if value of `${employer}` is IBM then query returns rows having employer_name exactly as IBM.

I tried changing where clause to     `where employer_name like '%${employer}%'` but its not working.

> EDIT 1

As per suggestions by pdpi, I tried to use double quotes instead of single quote around ${employer} but now I am getting `Parent exception: Invalid parameter index 1.` exception. Following is some part of stacktrace :

```
pt.webdetails.cda.dataaccess.QueryException: Found an unhandled exception:
        at pt.webdetails.cda.dataaccess.SimpleDataAccess.queryDataSource(SimpleDataAccess.java:299)
        at pt.webdetails.cda.dataaccess.AbstractDataAccess.doQuery(AbstractDataAccess.java:312)
        at pt.webdetails.cda.CdaEngine.doQuery(CdaEngine.java:51)
        at pt.webdetails.cda.CdaContentGenerator.doQuery(CdaContentGenerator.java:299)
        at pt.webdetails.cda.CdaContentGenerator.createContent(CdaContentGenerator.java:139)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet.doGet(GenericServlet.java:261)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet.doPost(GenericServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
    ava:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProto
    col.java:579)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: pt.webdetails.cda.dataaccess.QueryException: ReportDataFactoryException : Failed at query
    : select top 5
    emp.employer_name,count(emp.rinx_id) as candidate_count
    from tbl_cand_employment_details emp
    where emp.employer_name like "%${employer}%"
    group by emp.employer_name
    order by candidate_count desc; Parent exception: Invalid parameter index 1.
            at pt.webdetails.cda.dataaccess.PREDataAccess.performRawQuery(PREDataAccess.java:116)
            at pt.webdetails.cda.dataaccess.SimpleDataAccess.queryDataSource(SimpleDataAccess.java:288)
            ... 68 more
```

Please help me in forming this query.

> EDIT 2

My problem is solved now. Thanks to [this](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?70135-xaction-syntax-to-sql-like-xx-pattern-matching) question on Pentaho forum.

I modified my where clause as follows and now its working :

```
where employer_name like '%' + ${employer} + '%'
```

Comment: Hey there,

Are you using CDA queries, or Legacy?

You definitely should be using "%${employer}%" if you want to match the employer anywhere in employer_name. How is it that that variant isn't working? No results, same results? If you're not getting any results, would you be able to look at firebug's net panel and check whether any of the requests is failing, or whether the query is just returning nothing.

(disclaimer: I'm the CDE lead developer)

Comment: @pdpi, Thanks a lot for suggestions. I will try to use double quotes instead of single quotes and get back. Hope it will work.

Comment: @pdpi, where can I get more information about CDE query parameters? Actually I am not able to find proper documentation or  tutorials for Pentaho Community edition. Few books are there but those books refer to Enterprise edition.

Comment: From that last edit of yours, I gather that you're using Legacy queries. You're not finding any documentation because those are deprecated. I seriously recommend that you install CDA and query your data using that -- for both security and performance reasons. You can show up on IRC (channel ##pentaho at irc.freenode.net) and we can help with that.

Comment: @pdpi, I have downloaded CDE(Community Dashboard Editor) and using the same. Is CDE old and deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PDPI Says, you should use "%${employer}%" i.e. double quotes not single quotes. Then it should work.

Comment: Yeah, but he specifically said it didn't, which is odd.

Comment: @Codek, Thanks a lot for suggestions. I will try to use double quotes instead of single quotes and get back. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem using CDF and Action Sequence Files. It seems to me that you are trying to parameterise the query in Javascript. In that case, the component object has a *parameters* field which takes an array of parameters. Used like so;

```
parameters : [ [ "REGION", "region" ], [ "DISTRICT", "district" ],
                [ "SUB_DISTRICT", "subDistrict" ] ]
```

Also, there is a listener field which is used to refresh your component when the parameter is changed. See the CDF reference inside your Pentaho Solution for more details.